# Strange kotlin checkNotNullParameter error

Tags: kotlin

we received a crash on Firebase for a kotlin method:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter code
       at [redacted].DeliveryMethod.<init>(:2)
       at [redacted].DeliveryMethodsUpdater$addSingleDMInAd$clientCall$1.invokeSuspend(DeliveryMethodsUpdater.kt:121)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

the model is this one:

```
class DeliveryMethod() {
    lateinit var code: String
    lateinit var name: String
    lateinit var description: String

var isAddressRequired: Boolean? = null
var image: JSONObject? = null
var isDefault: Boolean = false

constructor(code: String) : this() {
    this.code = code
}

constructor(code: String, name: String, description: String, image: JSONObject? = null) : this() {
    this.code = code
    this.name = name
    this.description = description
    this.image = image
}
}
```

and the method:

```
private suspend fun addSingleDMInAd(
        adId: Long,
        deliveryMethodCode: String
    ): JoinAdDeliveryMethod? {
        var addedDeliveryMethod: JoinAdDeliveryMethod? = null
        val clientCall = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val cd = CountDownLatch(1)
            Client.getInstance().addDeliveryMethodInAd(
                adId,
                DeliveryMethod(deliveryMethodCode),
                object : NetworkCallback<JoinAdDeliveryMethod> {
                    override fun onSuccess(result: JoinAdDeliveryMethod) {
                        addedDeliveryMethod = result
                        cd.countDown()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(err: NetworkError?) {
                        addedDeliveryMethod = null
                        cd.countDown()
                    }
                }
            )
            cd.await()
        }
        clientCall.await()
        return addedDeliveryMethod
    }
```

now, I understand that that the constructor for `DeliveryMethod` is being called with a `null` value for `code`, but I don't understand why the exception only come up at this point. As you can see, the method param is also marked as non-null, and so are previous methods. Shouldn't the exception be thrown way before getting to the constructor call for `DeliveryMethod`?

EDIT:
this is the caller of `addSingleDMinAd()`:

```
 fun addDeliveryMethodsInAd(
        adId: Long,
        deliveryMethodCodesToAdd: List<String>,
        completionListener: (List<JoinAdDeliveryMethod?>) -> Unit
    ) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val updatedDms: MutableList<JoinAdDeliveryMethod?> = mutableListOf()
            for (deliveryCode in deliveryMethodCodesToAdd) {
                addSingleDMInAd(adId = adId, deliveryMethodCode = deliveryCode).run {
                    updatedDms.add(this)
                }
            }
            completionListener.invoke(updatedDms)
        }
    }
```

this is the java caller of the `addDeliveryMethodsInAd()` (this is inside an Android Service):

```
new DeliveryMethodsUpdater().addDeliveryMethodsInAd(
                            result.getId(),
                            deliveryMethodCodesToAdd,
                            updatedDMs -> {
                                // on failed delivery method request
                                for (JoinAdDeliveryMethod updatedDm : updatedDMs) {
                                    if (updatedDm == null) {
                                        //show error
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                AdDetailUpdater
                                        .getInstance()
                                        .updateSubscribersWithDeliveryMethods(result.getId(), updatedDMs);
                                return null;
                            }
                    );
```

Comment: When you go up the call stack, where is `deliveryMethodCode` coming from? How did it get there as null? Did you pass it from Java / via reflection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't the exception be thrown way before getting to the constructor call for DeliveryMethod?

Within Kotlin, it's not possible for a non-null parameter to be given a null value at runtime accidentally (because the code wouldn't have compiled in the first place). However, this can happen if the value is passed from Java. This is why the Kotlin compiler tries to protect you from Java's null unsafety by generating null-checks at the beginning of some methods (with the intrinsic `checkNotNullParameter` you're seeing fail here).

However, there is no point in doing that in private or suspend methods since they can only be called from Kotlin (usually), and it would add some overhead that might not be acceptable in performance-sensitive code. That is why **these checks are only generated for non-suspend public/protected/internal methods** (because their goal is to prevent misuse from Java).

This is why, if you manage to call `addSingleDMInAd` with a null argument, it doesn't fail with this error. That said, it would be interesting to see how you're getting the null here, because usually the checks at the public API surface are enough. Is some reflection or unsafe cast involved here?

EDIT: with the addition of the calling code, this clears up the problem. You're calling a method that takes a `List<String>` from Java, with a list that contains nulls. Unfortunately Kotlin only checks the parameters themselves (in this case, it checks that the list itself is not null), it doesn't iterate your list to check for nulls inside. This is why it didn't fail at the public API surface in this case.

---

Also, the way your model is setup is quite strange. It seems the `lateinit` is lying because depending on which constructor is used, the properties may actually not be set at all. It would be safer to mark them as nullable to account for when users of that class don't set the value of these properties. Doing this, you won't even need all secondary constructors, and you can just use default values:

```kotlin
class DeliveryMethod() {
    var code: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
    var image: JSONObject? = null,
) {
    var isAddressRequired: Boolean? = null
    var isDefault: Boolean = false
}
```

---

Other things of note about `addSingleDMInAd`:

- don't use `GlobalScope` in this case. If you need to run short-lived coroutines, provide them with a smaller scope that is cancelled when the work is not needed anymore - it ensures no coroutines are leaked. You can read more about the potential pitfalls of `GlobalScope` and possible replacements [in its own doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/). That said, you probably shouldn't be starting a coroutine at all anyway here, see next point.
- don't use `async {}` if you use `await()` right after - it's pointless to start something asynchronous if you wait for it right there. If you want to switch the context to IO, use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` instead. That said, you shouldn't even need to use the IO dispatcher here, see next point.
- don't use `CountDownLatch` for this purpose. The proper way to encapsulate an async API as a `suspend` function for coroutines is to use [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) (check its doc, it provides an example on how to use it). Once you use this, there is no need anymore for `Dispatchers.IO` because it will not be blocking the current thread anymore.

Comment: Yes I know the code is a mess, it's pre-existing. anyway, the method I reported it's only called from kotlin, the methods that call it are then called from java, if it was called directly I would expect this to be a problem but being called from kotlin I expected the null-safety to be checked. I gave it a try and it seems to be tha case:
javaMethod() calles kotlinMethod() with a null parameter, kotlinMethod() then calls addSingleDMInAd() again with null parameter, null safety is not enforced. I was expecting it to be in this case. thank you for other points, we'll see if we can fix them

Comment: @jack_the_beast no worries, I know what legacy code is :) I'm giving some advice in case you didn't know. Regarding the java caller, the null check should have caught the null value at the public boundary in the Kotlin code - so this is indeed strange, unless that particular piece of public Kotlin code called from java was compiled with a flag that disables the null-check. It'd be interesting to edit the question to show the Kotlin function called from Java.

Comment: @jack_the_beast About the Kotlin function called by Java with the null value, is it a `suspend` function by any chance? Those are not really supposed to be called by Java so there is no null check there either. If the Java code somehow provided a `Continuation` implementation in order to call the suspend function anyway, that could be the reason

Comment: I edited to include the caller methods. where can I find kotlin compilation flags?

Comment: A-ha! That explains it. You're passing a *list* of codes, and that list contains null values. Kotlin only checks for direct arguments, but it won't go through your lists passed from java to check for null. That's why it's not detected earlier in this case. I must say it's pretty uncommon to have null values in a list even in Java, though.

Comment: agreed on the list element checks, but addSingleDMInAd ha a String as param and it's not called from java. So why isn't the null detected at the point of calling addSingleDMInAd?
at this point the null value is certainly passd from java (unless there is something funny going on with the coroutines) and we are trying to detect if and when we're passing it, but then again this code base is a real mess and anything can happen

Comment: `addSingleDMinAd` is private, not called from Java, so Kotlin doesn't generate intrisic null checks in this method. Once you called `addDeliveryMethodsInAd` with a list that contains nulls from Java, you already fooled the Kotlin checks. After that, within Kotlin code and private method calls hierarchies, Kotlin trusts you with nullability.